# TypeScript - Rest API - Manage router / controller / Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api

I'm trying to transpose an initial Node project to a TypeScript one using Express and CoreModel.

In my initial project, the architecture is as the following exemple:

*to handle users*

accountRouter <- accountController <- User (Class) <- CoreModel (parent Class of user)

User (Class): contain specific method according User need

CoreModel (parent Class): contain global method as CRUD

I have tried to keep this way of doing on TypeScript, with few modifications

accountRouter

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { accountController } from '../controllers/accountController'
const router = Router()
const controller = new accountController()

router
    .route('/account')
    .get(controller.showUsers)

export default router
```

accountController

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { User } from '../models/User'
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { UserInformations, UserInformationsEdit } from '../models/interface'

export class accountController {

    private user: User = new User();


    public async showUsers(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response>  {
        
        try {
            console.log('this', this);
            const result = await this.user.findAll()

            return res.json(result)
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('error: ' + error.message)

        }

    }
}
```

User

```
import { CoreModel } from './CoreModel'

export class User extends CoreModel {};
```

CoreModel

```
import db from "../config/db"


export abstract class CoreModel {
    name: any;
    
    
    public async findAll(): Promise<any[]> {
                
        try {
            
            const result = await db.query(
                `SELECT * FROM "${this.name.toLowerCase()}"`
            );

            return result.rows;

        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('error: ' + error.message)
        }
    }
}
```

This way I'm able to transpile my code, but when I try to reach **http://localhost:1234/account**
I got

```
Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

According to me, since I'm getting an instance of accountController in the router, **this** should be accountController, isn't it ?

On a broader level,, I'm pretty sure that the way of I'm building my API in TS is not that good, I have tried to find example on internet to reproduce concept, but I didn't find some cases according my need.

I will be glad to take from you some input to get over it

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
router
    .route('/account')
    .get(controller.showUsers)
```

You pass `controller.showUsers` to the `get`-handler. By doing this, the `this` context will no longer refer to the `controller`. Fix it by using:

```
router
        .route('/account')
        .get(controller.showUsers.bind(controller))
```

As a side note: you may want to consider the [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) framework to build a robust API that is based on Typescript.

Comment: Many thanks for you response, it is working better now :D

I still have an error, since I added .bind() to the get handler, when my program come into the accountController, this = accountController { user: User {} }

then into the CoreModel this = User {}

The problem that I'm encountering is the way I'm handling this into CoreModel. I'm used to get Class name using this.name, here in my program I get

Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

You can find the entire code into CoreModel above

Thanks by advance,

Paul

Comment: [edit]
I got it with this.constructor.name.

About Nest.js I heard a lot about it, but my plan was too develop an API with the most i can do in TS vanilla. I would maybe reconsider that